# how to handle facebook logout button through code

Tags: android, facebook, integration

I am integrating Facebook with my Android application and I am using [this](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-facebook-integration-and-login/) link as Reference. After logging in automatically, the logout button is appearing. I am not handling anything for logout.

Is there any way to handle the logout button `onClick`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FB sdk button, then it will log user out on its click. else on click of you button just call

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for logout button. In which you can use intent to send it back to your login page as facebook do.

```
private void logoutUser(){
Intent I = new Intent(currentActivity.class, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(I);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom method in Application or Activity for logout.

```
    private void logoutApp()
    {
    // Logout from Facebook
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
    {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle Facebook logout button like..

```
Button logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            Intent login = new Intent(current activity, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But how to hide Facebook login button.After login that same button text is changing to "Logout".so I want to handle logout on that button.

Comment: post your onSuccess method code and you want to logout the app on same login activity or another activity..?